# What is the easing jQuery effect slower at the end?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to generate the effect of a slot machine ring spinning who starts to slow down until it stops. I have three animations:

1. The icon goes from `current position` to start position.
2. The icon goes from `start position` to `start position` (complete circle).
3. The icon goes from `start position` to `new position`.

The *first* and *second* animations have `linear` easing, but I don't know what should be the *third* one. I tried with (almost all) animations availables on jQuery UI library, but I don't get what I want.

Look:

[image]

[image]

**PS:** *I didn't know how to ask this answer properly, please feel free to edit it and delete this message.*

Answer (score 1):

These graphs show you everything.

https://jqueryui.com/easing/

Comment: Thanks, but, as I said, I tried with (almost all) easing animations availables on jQuery UI library. So the question if what I am doing wrong or what easing should I use

Comment: Sorry. I would suggest playing around with the duration parameter.